# how can I escape reserved characters as literals in a macro?

Tags: racket

Do I specify it as `\(` or some other means inside `syntax-rules`? Same question regarding square brackets and other reserved words.

Comment: Macros in racket are *tree-based*, not text-based. A macro has to return a valid tree, which means the parentheses that have meaning for that tree structure have to be balanced. With that in mind, can you elaborate more about what you mean?

Comment: I am following the bf tutorial (https://beautifulracket.com/bf/an-imperative-expander.html) where the "[" and "]" characters are part of the language. I'm wondering how I could implement the `bf-loop` macro w/o using the `br` package.

Comment: Are you using `syntax-parse`?

Comment: If you are using syntax-parse, the [`~brackets`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax-classes/index.html?q=~brackets#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse%2Fclass%2Fparen-shape..rkt%29._~7ebrackets%29%29) form from the `syntax-classes-lib` package might be useful.

Comment: I think you just put it in a string, like in the `parser.rkt` example on that page.